# "Spoiler" issues in editing

Tags: discussion, spoilers

When I'm writing a question or answer that contains plot points or secrets, I add...

> a spoiler!

However, when it comes to an extensive answer, all of which is a spoiler, I either need to add breaks between the sections, or have it all in one big block (yuck!) [like I have done here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169501/what-does-the-ending-to-dark-souls-2-mean/169539#169539), because if I create paragraph blocks between spoilers, all it does is:

> ! turn it into a regular blockquote,
>
> ! with each paragraph being led with an exclamation.

Is there a way to create paragraphs of spoilers without having to muck around, adding breaks and such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not spoiler the whole answer. If you consider all, or most of the answer a spoiler, the question is usually asking for one, and it should be obvious that reading it and its answers can spoil something. I'd add a **clear warning at the top of the answer that is sure to catch the reader's attention first,** if needed, and only use the spoiler markdown for *the worst* spoilers in the answer.

The main reason ***I*** think huge blocks of spoilers are not great is because you need to hover over to read them, and I often read the answer on my second screen as I try it out in-game on my primary screen, so hovering is not an option.

---

But to strictly answer your question...

> You can create paragraphs of spoilers by adding an empty HTML comment between the paragraphs (`<!-- -->`)

> Like so.